# How to get SSIS to stop waiting/processing at task above time limit?

Tags: ssms, ssis

So I have a couple SSIS packages that are run sequentially, scheduled through SQL Server Agent. Right now, I'm getting some errors where certain input data steps just wait indefinitely-- i.e access database locked exclusively by another user or other issues. I'm still in the process of figuring out why it will just wait at some of these steps.

However, is there any way for me to check how long I've been at a certain step, and error if it's been too long? I.e no individual step should take longer than 15 minutes as the absolute max, so I would like to have something like:

```
If step_processing_time > 15 minutes:
    Send error email message, fail package
```

Is this possible to do in SSIS? I tried googling but couldn't really find anything from what I searched.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timeouts on tasks; I don't know if you can on steps.